# SQL Server: procedure don't output anything?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a stored procedure which will fetch data from sys.databases and sys.database_files and combine this information into a single result set. Here's the code

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.PROC_getDbInfo
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    GO
    TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.dbinfo
    GO
    EXECUTE sp_msforeachdb 'insert into dbo.dbinfo 
            select  ''?'' as name,
                    type_desc, 
                    physical_name, 
                    state_desc, 
                    size * 1.0/128 as size_in_mb, 
                    max_size, 
                    growth * 1.0/128 as growth_in_mb, 
                    is_percent_growth,
                    is_read_only    
    from [?].sys.database_files'

    GO

    SELECT  @@SERVERNAME as instance_name,
        f.name,
        d.create_date,
        d.compatibility_level,
        d.collation_name,
        d.user_access_desc,
        d.state_desc,
        d.recovery_model_desc,
        d.page_verify_option_desc,
        d.log_reuse_wait_desc,
        f.type_desc, 
        f.physical_name, 
        f.state_desc, 
        f.size_in_mb, 
        f.max_size, 
        f.growth_in_mb, 
        f.is_percent_growth,
        f.is_read_only  
    FROM dbo.dbinfo AS f INNER JOIN
            sys.databases AS d
                ON f.name = d.name
    ORDER BY f.name
GO
```

When executing this procedure, I don't get any output. Why?

```
EXECUTE dbo.PROC_getDbInfo
```

Comment: Probably because there are no rows in sys.databases with name = '?'

Comment: Noup, query sp_msforeachdb from the google...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of `GO`s, your stored procedure only contains `SET NOCOUNT ON`.

Remove the `GO`s.

Answer (score 2):

It's because all your sproc will actually be doing is:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
```

As the next line after that is GO - that ends that batch, and so the sproc will have been created just with that SET NOCOUNT statement in!

Answer (score 1):

That's because the stored procedure will only run up to the first GO - the rest are separate statements. Your stored procedure will have been created containing just SET NOCOUNT ON - the rest will have been run just once; when you actually created the stored procedure - at which point they were treated as separate commands.